# Check if ngOnDestroy is called on a route change

Tags: angular

I have a child form component that gets created in material tabs:

```
<md-tab *ngFor="let selectedEntity of selectedEntities; let i=index">
    <template md-tab-label>{{selectedEntity.resource.name}}
        <i class="fa fa-times" (click)="onTabClose(i)"></i>
    </template>
    <child-form [entity]="selectedEntity"></child-form>
</md-tab>
```

I'm using `ngOnDestroy` to show a material dialog asking if the user wants to save when closing the tab.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.promptService.open(this);
  };
```

However, since the current state is saved in a service, I don't need to show the prompt when the user changes the route, only when they close a tab.

Can I (and if so, **how** can I) check if a route change is causing the child component to be destroyed?

Comment: one way would be to listen to router events and if you receive routerNavigationStart event know that routing is in progress

Comment: I basically did something like that, I'll post the whole thing as an answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I managed to do here is create a boolean property that gets set to `true` on a `NavigationStart` event and gets set to `false` on the `NavigationEnd` event. That way I can open the dialog only if the route navigation has ended. Here is how I got around the problem in several steps:

1.I created a boolean called `inNavigation` in my `prompt.service.ts`

2.Then, in the service constructor, I subscribed to the navigation events and set `inNavigation` accordingly:

```
constructor(private dialog: MdDialog, public router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.inNavigation = true;
      } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.inNavigation = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

3.Then I used that boolean property to check if I should open the prompt dialog:

```
public open(entity: any): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.inNavigation == false) {
      let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<PromptComponent>;
      dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PromptComponent);
      dialogRef.componentInstance.entity = entity;
      return dialogRef.afterClosed();
    }
  }
```

I put all of this in the prompt service, because I won't have to change every single component and I can still use something more simple to achieve what I wanted:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.promptService.open(this);
  }
```